# How can I make a download link which downloads data directly from a DB in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, byte, varbinarymax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Download A file stored in SQL DB in Binary Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902421/how-to-download-a-file-stored-in-sql-db-in-binary-format)

I stored some MS word docs in SQL Server. When I wanna download them, I save them as a file on server first then user can download them, but I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve saving the file to the server filesystem...

Comment: You could put the data directly in the response from the Web server.

Comment: Your title is different from your question. What are you actually asking?

Comment: @James - I don't really see a mismatch between the two? They are asking how to stream binary data held in SQL Server without the intermediate step of saving to the file system first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom HttpHandler implementing IHttpHandler. See [IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) in MSDN. Set the appropriate MIME-type and redirect the binary data from your database to the HttpContext's OutputStream.

An example (guessed, not tested) for a custom handler called **Docs.ashx**:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class Docs : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("fileSourceForDemonstration.docx"))
        {
            streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you could do it that way you could do it just as well with a single .aspx page taking a querystring parameter of some sort. The code will be much the same either way though.

Comment: @Chris The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030433/byte-serving-pdfs-from-sql-varbinary) seems to solve it the .aspx-way. Answered by another Chris :-)